# How to change Jenkins/Jetty max header size

Tags: jenkins, jetty, embedded-jetty

running a Jenkins server with the embedded Jetty, I get errors regarding too big headers in the Jenkins log:

> Feb 15, 2017 3:18:15 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog warn
>   WARNING: header full: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8192

I'd like to increase the Jetty max header size but can't find how to do it, in the case of a Jenkins... I can't find any Jetty config file and don't know if I can set the limit on the Jenkins command line (and what would be the name of the variable to define).

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using the built-in Jetty found in the self-running jenkins.war, you cannot adjust that value.

You can only adjust the maximum number of parameters.

```
--maxParamCount=N   = set the max number of parameters allowed in a form submission to protect
                      against hash DoS attack (oCERT #2011-003). Default is 10000.
```

Either deploy the war to a full blown container which you can then adjust the value, or change how you use Jenkins to not send excessive URI or HTTP headers (such as using POST vs GET).

To adjust the Jetty 9 header buffer maximum size, you'd adjust the `requestHeaderSize` in the `HttpConfiguration` for the `ServerConnector` that you want that new setting to exist in.

Answer (score 2):

Add this parameter to jenkins config:

```
JENKINS_ARGS="--requestHeaderSize=258140"
```

Comment: I have set in JENKINS_OPTS . That works for me.