# How to change jetty.httpConfig.requestHeaderSize in a read-only container?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jetty

How to pass configuration such as `jetty.httpConfig.requestHeaderSize` to jetty via environment variables, in order to change the configuration of existing image in a read-only container in kubernetes (or docker)?

Comment: Refer- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42255274/how-to-change-jenkins-jetty-max-header-size

Answer (score 0):

*Note: that it is rarely a good idea to increase the size of `jetty.httpConfig.requestHeaderSize`.  Larger sizes often mean your web application has a requirement that makes using it on all web browsers not possible.  A larger size is also known to trip up various load balancers, caches, and other intermediaries.  If you are increasing the size, stop and evaluate why, and fix that.  If you are decreasing the size, then go right ahead.*

The `jetty.httpConfig.requestHeaderSize` is a jetty-start property.

The properties that jetty-start uses come from a configuration in the `${jetty.base}` directory (usually something like a `${jetty.base}/start.d/server.ini` file).

You will need to influence the startup of Jetty itself.

One of the following:

- the configuration stored in the `${jetty.base}` directory.
- the command line used to start Jetty to add that property.

  - Either the script that runs `start.jar`.
  - Or the `jetty.sh` configuration by editing the `/etc/default/jetty` file.

Comment: Via environment variables?

Comment: No, Jetty doesn't look at Environment variables.  Only the `jetty.sh` does, but it gets the environment variables from the `/etc/default/jetty` file.